# qemu-mipsel-static can't find /dev/urandom

Tags: mips, emulation, qemu

I tried to run binary file with `qemu-mipsel-static` :

```
 qemu-mipsel-static  -L ../ ./MyBinary
```

But process is crashed when it tried to access to  `/dev/urandom`

```
│access("../dev/urandom", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix that?